# JSON encoding from while loop not returning any results PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to create json response from a database results, the issue i am having is that, if i request one item i get the result as i need it but i am not receiving the collection with the code below.

The data is there i can see it when i do a var_dump.

Here is the code.

```
        $i = 0;
        while ( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array ( $stmt3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
            $rows [] = array (
                    'Note Id' => $obj ['NoteId'],
                    'Patient Id' => $obj ['PatientID'],
                    'Note Text' => $obj ['NoteText'],
                    'Date of Note' => $obj ['DateOfNote'],
                    'Category Id' => $obj ['CategoryId'] 
            );
            $i ++;
        } 

echo json_encode ( $rows);
```

Here is an extract from the var_dump

> ```
> array(27) {
>   [0]=>
>   array(5) {
>     ["Note Id"]=>
>     int(66)
>     ["Patient Id"]=>
>     string(36) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
>     ["Note Text"]=>
>     string(70) "Remember to set "
>     ["Date of Note"]=>
>     object(DateTime)#4 (3) {
>       ["date"]=>
>       string(26) "2012-01-30 16:13:04.033000"
>       ["timezone_type"]=>
>       int(3)
>       ["timezone"]=>
>       string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
>     }
>     ["Category Id"]=>
>     int(1)
>   }
>   [1]=>
>   array(5) {
>   ["Note Id"]=>
>     int(67)
>     ["Patient Id"]=>
>     string(36) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
>     ["Note Text"]=>
>     string(61) "Keep having"
>     ["Date of Note"]=>
>     object(DateTime)#5 (3) {
>       ["date"]=>
>       string(26) "2012-01-30 16:13:52.763000"
>       ["timezone_type"]=>
>       int(3)
>       ["timezone"]=>
>       string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
>     }
>     ["Category Id"]=>
>     int(1)
>   }
> ```

Comment: And what is the result of json_encode?

Comment: Besides from what @MichalBieda asked, try checking [**json_last_error()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php).

Comment: in Postman, im getting no result with the status code is 200, therefore no errors . if i change to echo json_encode ( $rows[0]); i get the first element from the json

Comment: im getting the following error Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';